# Is a word "spleak painly" typo?

Tags: word-meaning

"Kanga, I see the time has come to spleak painly."

This is from "Winni-the-Pooh". I didn't search the words "spleak painly". I think it would be "speak plainly". Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. In normal usage, yes: "speak plainly" would be the correct expression. "Spleak" is not a word of any kind, and "painly" is not an adverb that I can get any meaning from.

On the other hand, the author is using this as an example of a [Spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism), where, usually in a fit of excitement, the speaker mixes up the beginnings of the words. The context shows us this:

> Piglet, who had never been really fond of baths, shuddered a long
>   indignant shudder, and said in as brave a voice as he could: "Kanga, I
>   see that the time has come to spleak painly."
>   "Funny little Roo," said Kanga, as she got the bath–water ready.
>   "I am not Roo," said Piglet loudly. "I am Piglet!"
>   "Yes, dear, yes," said Kanga soothingly. "And imitating Piglet's voice too!"

Piglet is trying to tell Kanga that he's not really Roo, though she's not really paying attention. Piglet was always trying to be brave and not quite succeeding. That's the author's point here, which is why he used the Spoonerism.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.That is to say, Piglet was so excited and nervous that he said it wrong. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Piglet, as you probably know, is very excitable. John Fiedler so perfectly matched his character in the movies.

Comment: spoonerisms are associated with being nervous, if you mee what I sean.

Comment: There is also dramatic irony. Kanga is perfectly well aware that Piglet isn't Roo, but is pretending not to notice.

Comment: Dramatic irony? I don't really see that here. But you're right that Kanga knows who Piglet is. I had forgotten this story, though I read it to my kids often when they were young and was one of our favorites. "It is hard to be brave," said Piglet, sniffing slightly, "when you're only a Very Small Animal." Thanks for the memory. :-)